# Qt convert ISO date to QDate

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Hello I am newbie in Qt and new learning Qt. And for now I've problem to convert ISO date to Qdate. Example I've ISO date like this:

> 2015-05-17T05:16:22.126Z

and now how to convert it to be like this "yyyy-mm-dd" or "yyyymmdd"? Please help me. :D

Comment: please show us the code you are using

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your answer:

```
QString str = "2015-05-17T05:16:22.126Z";
QDateTime dateTime = QDateTime::fromString(str, "yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.zzzZ");
QString newStr = dateTime.toString("yyyy-mm-dd");
```

(don't hesitate to see the documentation of the Qt framework, this [page](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdatetime.html#fromString-2) for example)